# Polymer.dart <property>Changed Functionality Not Working With Map

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am building a Dart app using Polymer.dart.  I have a map in my polymer element as follows:

```dart
@observable Map theData = toObservable({
  'name':   '',
  'phone':  '',
  'email':  ''
});
```

...and have the following method set up:

```dart
theDataChanged() {
  // ...
}
```

However, `theDataChanged()` function is **not** called after the following operations are made:

```dart
theData['name'] = 'test1';
theData.putIfAbsent('new', () => 'test2');
```

Are the `<property>Changed()` methods not supported for `Map`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open bug and a workaround

[toObservable() does not work correctly with a Map and template repeat](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15407)